# image gets distorted when I try to bring it in with css or html

Tags: css

when I try to import an image using css, it always distorts the image. the image on my desktop is 180px X 80px, I bring it in with css like this:

```
.image{
    background: url(trya5.png) no-repeat 50% 70%;
}
```

when it appears in my browser it is like twice the size of the dimensions of the original image file. If I reduce the dimensions of the image file in half and save it in my project folder, then it fits the size I need in the browser but it looks fuzzy and loses quality. help?

Comment: First thing is your syntax for your css selector is wrong you have a `]` where you should have `}`

Comment: it's not like that in my actual code lol, that's not the problem

Comment: How big (height and width) is the whatever element that the class `.image` is attached to

Comment: it doesn't seem to matter, I can change the height and width to anything and it looks distorted. obvs i started with the dimensions of the actual image file but it doesn't matter

Comment: Your image is made of a matrix of pixels, colored dots that make up the image. The resolution is the amount of pixels wide X high. 200px X 300px for example... If you enlarge the image too much you will get ***digital image interpolation*** also known as pixelate or some refer to as pixelization. See the following article for more info on digital image interpolation https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-interpolation.htm In short if you do not want the image to pixelate, you need to specify the resolution to be close to the original size.

Comment: how do you do that?  like i have a .jpg file with certain height width and res, and then if i try to bring it in using css using the same dimensions it still looks distorted

Comment: Have you tried setting background-size? There are many possibilities, including ensuring that you don't enlarge the image more than looks OK.